# undefined control sequense error in xepersian.sty

Tags: xepersian

I have a LaTeX document using `xepersian`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\listfiles

\title{نمونه مقاله}
\author{نویسنده}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
این یک نوشته آزمایشی است.
\end{abstract}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

When I want to export pdf from it I get the error:
`Undefined control sequence` in `xepersian.sty` file in the line: `\PersianAlphs`

I also get this *File list in my log:

```
 *File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
xepersian.sty    2015/02/02 v16 Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontenc.sty
eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
xepersian-persiancal.sty    2012/07/25 v0.2 provides Persian calendar
xepersian-mathsdigitspec.sty    2014/11/21 v1.1.0 Unicode Persian maths digits in XeLaTeX
bidi.sty    2015/02/17 v16.9 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX
iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX
biditools.sty    2015/02/16 v0.4 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
latex-xetex-bidi.def    2015/02/01 v1.1.9 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' for XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2013/04/26 v0.8 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engine
article-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.4 bidi adaptations for standard article class for XeTeX engine
graphicx-xetex-bidi.def    2012/01/01 v0.4 bidi adaptations for graphicx package for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def    2013/05/22 v0.95 making sure that bidi is the last package loaded
loadingorder-xepersian.def    2012/01/01 v0.3 making sure that xepersian is the last package loaded
fontspec-xetex-xepersian.def    2014/07/10 v0.1 fixes for fontspec-xetex package
footnote-xepersian.def    2013/04/26 v0.4 footnote macros for xepersian package

article-xepersian.def    2010/07/25 v0.2 adaptations for standard article class

t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
***********
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I try your example (after adding `\settextfont{Scheherazade}`, any other font supporting Persian should do) and removing the calls to `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `lmodern` (that shouldn't be used with XeLaTeX), I get no error.

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried it but it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` at the beginning and add what you get in the log file after `*File List`?

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your comment(*File List)

Comment: When you process a file with XeLaTeX, you get a file with name ending in `.log`. Look into it (it's just a text file) and you'll find `*File List*`

Comment: or can you edit the question to add the new code (the code after @egreg 's first comment)

Comment: I can not find `*File List` in the log file.

Comment: Did you add `\listfiles` at the beginning of the document?

Comment: Yes I added it.

Comment: @s_puria You have to go past the error, not stopping when it appears.

Comment: @egreg I use LaTeXilla. It automatically stops after the error.

Comment: @s_puria Can you run `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode <filename>` from a terminal? Here `<filename>` stands for the actual name of your test file.

Comment: First thing i notice, is that your packages are quite old. An update might be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have not set the Persian text font.

```
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/
%\setlatintextfont{Liberation Serif}
```

Comment: I added it. Now, I have the pdf output but it has not persian text in it and has this:
`g__fontspec_latinfont_familyMapping=tex-text,ExternalLocation,BoldFont=lmroman10-
bold,BoldItalicFont=lmroman10-bolditalic,ItalicFont=lmroman10-italic,SmallCapsFont=lmromancaps10-
regular,SlantedFont=lmromanslant10-regular,BoldSlantedFont=lmromanslant10-bold,lmroman10-
g__fontspec_persianfont_familyScript=Parsi,Language=Parsi,Mapping=parsidigits„FreeFarsi regular`

Comment: @s_puria, there seems to be something wrong with your texlive installation. You might need to update the `fontspec` package.

Comment: I updates texlive and all packages. It fixed the problem.